# Store opening times

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I am designing a wordpress page and wish to add a html/php widget to the sidebar so that it automatically works out the time of the day and check whether that time the store is open or closed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want help while you write the software or do you want someone to write the software for you?

Comment: I want to embed this: $storeopens = mktime(8,0,0); // Opening at 8AM
$storecloses = mktime(21,0,0); // Closing at 9PM
if($storeopens > time() < $storecloses)
into html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mktime(8,0,0) < time() && time() < mktime(21,0,0))
```

Editted for incorrect operators and Larry's illogical but correct query on php if statement structure :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the very quick reply, however I am a real novice at this, would you be able to embed that with html so that i could see how it works. once again thank you :)

Comment: No, I couldn't. If you want to hire me to write part of your website it will cost you, if you can't even do basic PHP use an online guide.

Comment: @JV, are you sure that expression is valid? I'd think it be more like `if(mktime(8,0,0) > time() && time() < mktime(21,0,0))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, but at the moment niether of them is working on my lamp server so I'll have to get back to you on that ;P

Comment: Yes it needed the and operator, also the first operator was the wrong way round.